# Change value on POST before saving

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if   request.method == 'GET':
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'rest_framework/index.html', {'request':request, 'queryset':queryset})
    elif request.method == 'POST':
    post_mutable = request.POST.copy()
        serializer = TestSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    serializer.context = {'request': request}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.data['test'] = "testing"
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can you change a data value before saving?  I would like to change the TextField "test".

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `.save_object(obj)` method on your TestSerializer class. See [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#saving-object-state).